# How to use predicates on expanded entities in breeze

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, breeze

Lets say that I have entity called `Foo` and it has a list of `Bars`. `Bars` also contains a field called `isDeleted` which indicates that the particular bar has been soft deleted. I want to be able to query for a specific `Foo` and filter out the `Bars` that are soft deleted inside of a Javascript file using Breeze. I thought that this would work...

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Foo')
        .where('Id', '==', id).and('Bars.IsDeleted', '==', false)
        .expand('Bars');
```

However it does not, can someone tell me how to do this in breeze? If the only solution is to code a method in the `BreezeController` and use standard LINQ syntax then I am fine with that but I just want to see if it will work at all in Breeze first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now Breeze does not support filtering of 'expands'. i.e. only returning the 'expanded' entities that meet a certain criteria.  This is because very few back end servers and persistence libraries provide a mechanism to support this.

What you may be able to do however is **invert** the query to get what you need. i.e.

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Bars').expand('Foo')
    .where(new breeze.Predicate('Foo.Id', 'eq', id)
                 .and('IsDeleted', 'eq', false));
```

This assumes that 'Bar' entities each have a scalar 'Foo' property.

This will return just the 'Bars' that you want each with its associated 'Foo'
entity. This works because Breeze allows nested scalar predicates. i.e. 'Foo.Id'.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `.where()` chains on a query [will automatically "AND" together](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_where).  If you want to do this explicity, you need to use the [breeze.Predicate](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/Predicate.html) object as your where parameter like so:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Foo').expand('Bars')
    .where(new breeze.Predicate('Id', 'eq', id)
                     .and('Bars.IsDeleted', 'eq', false));
```

You can also choose to use `.or` or any other method on the `Predicate` object, most of them chain properly.

**Edit**: Here is an example of using multiple `.where` calls:

```
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Foo').expand('Bars')
                .where('Id', 'eq', id)
                .where('Bars.IsDeleted', 'eq', false);
```